# Using TortoiseGit with Google App Engine

Tags: git, google-app-engine, authentication, tortoisegit

On Windows 7 64-bit, I have used the `gcloud auth login` command to initialize the authorization to my Google Developers Console. Then I used the `gcloud init my-awesome-project-555` command to initialize my local git repo.

Now I want to use TortoiseGit to perform push/pull operations on my local repo but it's not working because of an authentication failure.

I noticed that the `gcloud.cmd` is being used for a local credential helper but I only get an empty cmd window popup when I try to push or pull. When I close the window, I get the regular username/password dialogs (probably falling back to wincred) and I enter my Google developer console username and password but then authentication fails anyways.

My project is hosted on https://source.developers.google.com/

Comment: Check if while pasting the remote repo URL you didn't get an accidental space in the end. That was what caused a "400" error while trying to do any operation on the remote repo on my end.